Who hates Ripple?
There are a few people that constantly downvote & attempt to close Ripple questions.
This is a callout to them - who are you? Why are you doing this?

I don't hate Ripple.  I hate the Bitcoin stackexchange being abused (my opinion) by inclusion with non-bitcoin questions.   StackExchange provides a mechanism called upvote, downvote, and close.  I use these to communicate that I think Ripple is off topic.

There, and I voted to close this question too.   Sorry if that offends you.  Don't take it personally.

@StephenGornick well, this is meta ... usually less pedantic about closing questions. But feel free.

I think personally that Ripple is not particularly on-topic here, but I know other people think differently. I do not downvote Ripple questions because they are about Ripple, but I don't really like them.

wether or not I hate ripple is offtopic, I just consider they are abusing this stackexchange with offtopic ripple questions and marketing, they need their own ripple.stackexchange.

This is still an issue, although -from what I gather- it was decided that crypto-currencies are on-topic. If Ripple were off-topic, why would it have a tag!? I wish these people would just add ripple to their list of ignored tags and be done with it.

Who is doing it is irrelevant. The important question is why. Ripple questions are getting close votes, but nobody's spoken against Ripple's inclusion in this discussion. (edit: AntonAnsagar has now, and Stephen Gornick posted something that can kinda be interpreted either way.) There are two possible reasons for that:

People voting to close are unaware of the previously linked discussion. I think this is unlikely; you need 500 rep to cast one, and I would imagine that somebody who's been here that long would have visited meta.
People voting to close feel that replying to that post wouldn't convince anybody, and that making close votes on Ripple questions is best approach to winning people over.

What should we do? Nothing, until 1) they make a meta post explaining their position or 2) gain enough support to actually close questions. 
One more thing to remember: this isn't Us vs. Them. We're a community of people, and while we might disagree on some minor points, we're still going to build a kick-ass reference site.

Good post, I agree.

Well, I think it is "people who accept community-backed decisions" vs. "people who abuse the system and ignore the decisions taken democratically"

I don't hate ripple but my scam/bs radar is very much warning me about it. Here is why: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=147789.0
Obviously 5-6 accounts are trying to promote Ripple here. These accounts are most probably owned by people who have a stake in Ripple or OpenCoin or whatever.
You are abusing this SE to promote your project/company.
I've given my thoughts with my answer here https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/362/2995 and in the comments.

"These accounts are most probably owned by people who have a stake in Ripple or OpenCoin or whatever." Not only is this an ad hominem, but it's also not falsifiable. In other words, there is no way for me to prove that I don't own OpenCoin stock.

Whether that statement is true or not does not change the fact the project is being marketed through this site. If they are Ripple "enthusiasts", start another SE or forum etc. Don't abuse the traffic this SE generates from Bitcoin.

The world of alternative currencies and alternative money exchanges is still very new.  There are good arguments for why ripple might succeed or might fail, and arguments for why it might be great for bitcoin, and arguments for why it might be bad for bitcoin, etc etc.  There are arguments for why it might be a boon to the developers, and arguments for why it might be a way bigger boon to the world, in a way that would make whatever profit they make from it all a drop in the bucket compared to its overall positive impact.  So I doubt that talking about it here is bad or inappropriate.

I'm not saying talking about Ripple is bad or inappropriate. Please talk to your hearts content where ever you want. This SE is not the place for it. I'm just saying using this SE to promote Ripple is inappropriate.

Ripple is offtopic here, they need their own stackexchange and stop spamming here, imo altchains are welcome, but ripple is not an altchain anf have nothing to do here, even if the ripple guys are very good at marketing and manipulation.
